# Error in sequelize and typescript integration within nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy nestJs with sequelize using typescript.

I am following this tutorial:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#sequelize-integration

```
[00:22:10] Starting compilation in watch mode...

node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/model/model/model.d.ts:10:31 - error TS2417: Class static side 'typeof import("/var/www/vhosts/curem/temp/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/model/model/model").Model' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof import("/var/www/vhosts/curem/temp/node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model").Model'.
  The types returned by 'init(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Model<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'MS'.
      'MS' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Model<any, any>'.

10 export declare abstract class Model<TModelAttributes extends {} = any, TCreationAttributes extends {} = TModelAttributes> extends OriginModel<TModelAttributes, TCreationAttributes> {
                                 ~~~~~

node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts:12:5 - error TS2416: Property 'model' in type 'Sequelize' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Sequelize'.
  Type '<TCreationAttributes, TModelAttributes>(model: string | ModelType<TCreationAttributes, TModelAttributes>) => ModelCtor<Model<any, any>>' is not assignable to type '(modelName: string) => ModelCtor<Model<any, any>>'.
    Type 'import("/var/www/vhosts/curem/temp/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/model/model/model").ModelCtor<import("/var/www/vhosts/curem/temp/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/model/model/model").Model<any, any>>' is not assignable to type 'import("/var/www/vhosts/curem/temp/node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model").ModelCtor<import("/var/www/vhosts/curem/temp/node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model").Model<any, any>>'.
      Type 'ModelCtor<Model<any, any>>' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'.
        The types returned by 'init(...)' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'Model<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'MS'.
            'MS' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Model<any, any>'.

12     model<TCreationAttributes, TModelAttributes>(model: string | ModelType<TCreationAttributes, TModelAttributes>): ModelCtor;
       ~~~~~

[00:22:13] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: What versions of packages are you using? Seems like a types problem

Answer (score 14):

I was just seeing this problem, it is related to the last version they released of sequalize.

Try the version:

```
"sequelize": "6.6.2"
```

Comment: Downgrade to `6.6.2` solved my problem. It seems something wrong with version `6.6.4`.

Comment: Why did I downgrade but the error still appears, right?

Comment: It didn't work for me but I forgot to remove the caret which upgraded the package ^6.6.2 => 6.6.2 and then it worked, thanks.

Comment: @HatemSat thanks, removing the mark '^' turned out to be a differentiator and now it's working

Comment: Do you know if there is an open issue in place? A few months has passed and this is not fixed yet...

Answer (score 2):

Currently all versions higher than `6.6.2` aren't works correctly.

Try to change version in `package.json` file to `"sequelize": "6.6.2"`

If it didn't help check your extension from class Model in your own model.

```
@Table
export class User extends Model<User, IUser>
```

Change to:

```
@Table
export class User extends Model
```